# runSchedule job every hour in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

*i'm working with nodejs and Mongodb. i want to run job every user define hours using npm [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) but its did't work.*

***Here is my code***

```
    var schedule = require('node-schedule');
    var  mailTimer = 1;
    var intMail = schedule.scheduleJob('* * '+mailTimer+' * *', function(){
          console.log('its run');
    });

//its means its run every 1 hour.
```

Comment: What is the response that you get?

Comment: nothing get any response.

Comment: There needs to be one more `*` at the end of the input string if I'm not wrong. Add it and check the response.

Comment: yes..you are right but how can i run every hours? i need to like * * /1 * * * * or not?

Comment: `* * 1 * * *` should do it. Try!

Comment: yaaa.. thank you . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crontab config should be `0 */'+mailTimer+' * * *`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.hour = 1;
var intMail = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
      console.log('its run');
});
```

You can use other rules to set like :

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    |
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

Here's another example using other rules:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 14, minute: 30, dayOfWeek: 0}, function(){
    console.log('Time for tea!');
});
```

More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule#recurrence-rule-scheduling)

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for?

Comment: oh yes, i'm try its but wait 1 hour for response.

Comment: instead of `rule.hour = 1` use `rule.second = 5`. If it works for 5 second interval. It will definitely work for 1 hour with the hour rule.

Comment: ohh yes sorry i forgot it. i will try this.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be one more `*` at the end of the input string if I'm not wrong. Add it and check the response. For one hour you can use `* * 1 * * *`